# Can we do a Spearman's corelation between a continuous and an categorical ordered variable (0,1,2,4)?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, small-sample, spearman-rho, kruskal-wallis-test

just a question that may be already answered here, is it possible to perform a Spearman's rank correlation ( to find a correlation) between a continuous variable and a categorical ( ordered) variable like 0,1,2,3 ( the ordered variable represents disease stade, it's more than 2 levels...)

The kruskall test was NS (almost S) but the Spearman shows significant results the sample is small < 20...

Any ideas ? thank you for your response.

Comment: Sure, it’s reasonable to do Spearman correlation here. What are you trying to test, though, that you’re doing a Kruskall test? This sounds like it might be an XY problem where you have problem X that you aren’t sure how to solve, but you think method Y (Spearman correlation) is a way to approach X, so you ask about Y instead of your real question, X.

Comment: Thanks Dave,Y is the ordered variable
X is continuous
looking into correlation between them,

Comment: What are you trying to do with your analysis? Why does correlation matter to you? Why might the Kruskall test help solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, I want to try to tell that based on quantative measures found X (non invasive methods ) we can tell that disease severity will be corrrelated to 0,1,2 ....  the KS was used not for correlation but to see if there is diffrence between disease grade groups (y) based on the measures (x) , but my main aim is the correlation.